# When to Break Up a Collection into Smaller Collections

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I've been setting up a MongoDB application and am having trouble understanding when to break up a collection into smaller related collections.

This is for a socket based Trivia application where each Collection is of the "Game" schema. The Game schema has an array of player objects (JSON example provided below).

```
{
id: 12345,
title: "my trivia game",
players: [
    {
        _id: 9876
        name: "John",
        socketID: "abcdef",
        answers: [1, 3, 4, 5, null, null], // indicates the answer submitted
        score: 10
    }, //etc, etc typically an array of 20 to 50 players
    ],
questions: [] // array of questions and their answers
}
```

When an answer is submitted (via sockets) the Game is queried, the player is pulled from the array, and the players object is updated to have their newly submitted answer and score.

```
// pseudo-code javascript, for Mongoose schema update
// playerID, questionID, answerValue from socket submission
Game.findById(id, function(err, game) {
    var player = game.players.id(playerID); //find the player in the object
    player.answers[questionID] = answerValue; //track their submission
    game.save();
});
```

Is there value in breaking the Players out into a separate collection? My concern is that multiple players being updated at the same time might cause data loss or locking issues - but I don't know enough about MongoDB to determine if that is true.

With the players set up as a separate collection, it is less likely that a document will have two changes being recorded at the same time.

Comment: do you have an estimation on how big the players and questions arrays might grow to be?

Comment: There are typically 20 to 50 players in the players array.
The questions array is typically ~20, but is not updated during gameplayer.
The Game object is updated during game play to change an "ActiveQuestion" attribute